# What's the quickest way to learn objective-c for a PHP experienced developer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am not sure if StackOverflow is the right service to ask this question but I believe it worths to try.

I am an experienced PHP developer and now interested in building some iPhone apps. I have searched on Google for tutorials about objective-c but couldn't find a good one for beginners.

Do you have any suggestion, something like Objective-c for dummies? :)

Thanks again.

Comment: Also see previous question [Objective-C Resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources) with a lot of good links in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Programming in Objective C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672325861) is a great book to start off with.  It's written in a similar fashion as Kernigan and Ritchie's C book.  It starts at the very beginning and doesn't make too many assumptions about prior knowledge.

Comment: +1 for Kochan's book. He's got an excellent writing style and does a decent job explaining the language. He does not, however, cover Cocoa APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt using this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-3rd/dp/0321503619](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619)

It's really fantastic and covers everything you'll need for making Cocoa Apps.  A lot of the stuff you'll learn there is directly transferable to writing iPhone apps.

Another thing you can do is find a few open source iPhone apps to learn from, a good place to start would be http://www.appsamuck.com/, they have a bunch of examples apps you can take a look at.

If you're just looking for an obj-c language guide Apple has a pretty good one:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Answer (score 1):

Start programming exclusive in objective-c.  Since objective-c is a strict superset of c if you know c or a c like language you are 90% there.  If you know an oo language you are 95% there.  The way I did this was to jump right into an iphone app.  There are loads of tutorials, some excellent, for beginning iphone programmers.  Also since the iphone sdk is huge, and growing all the time, its best to jump right into an iphone app instead of first learning objective-c.  This haas the advantage of familiarizing you with the sdk as well as the objective-c language.

From being a complete novice in objective-c it took me about 2 months to get an app in the app store.  Not in the top 10 but a respectable showing given this was my first app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree, I will jump into my first iphone app very soon which will fetch XML results from one of my web service APIs and display data on the screen. It will help me to have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get started with iphone very quickly. check out

http://mattgemmell.com/2009/07/14/iphone-development-emergency-guide

Plus you can go thru the entire iphone reference library at apple's website

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend the Big Nerd Ranch classes enough. Expensive, assuming your company isn't covering it, but they're great. I went, along with two coworkers, a few years ago. I'd already been working with Cocoa for years, but I found a lot of value. The two folks who attended with me were newbies and learned a ton.

Otherwise, Aaron's book or any of the books published by Apress and written/edited by Dave Mark are all great.